# Running time in Python

Tags: python, time

I wrote code to find the current time in Python. Its result is: 'Time: 20:49:08' my current time. Can I make the time show in seconds running, so the value of `%S` increases?

Code:

```
import time
def current_time():
   t = time.localtime()
   current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
   print('Time:',current_time)
```

I expect a running result without a GUI interface.

Comment: Sure just print it as regularly as you need using a while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.stdout.write('\r' + YOUR_STRING)` along with the `sys.stdout.flush()` to print the same line at the same location.

```
import time
import sys


def show_current_time():
    count = 10
    while True:
        t = time.localtime()
        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
        sys.stdout.write('\r' + f'Time: {current_time}')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
        count -= 1
        if count == 0:
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    show_current_time()
```

In this example, I printed the time for 10 seconds. You can update it as necessary.

Demo:

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Use stdout.write and '\r' instead of print:

```
import time
from sys import stdout

def current_time():
   t = time.localtime()
   current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)
   stdout.write('\r' + 'Time: ' + current_time)
   
for i in range(20):
    current_time()
    time.sleep(.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean to keep printing on the same place? Remove the print() from your function. You must use end='' to keep the cursor on the same line. This works. Use ctl-C to stop it.

```
import time

def current_time():
    t = time.localtime()
    return time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)


while True:
    print(f'time {current_time()}\r', end="")
```